# Translation Url not reached

Tags: elementary-website

I would like to get permissions to save translations but this url https://translators-slack.elementary.io/ not reached.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have more success using the link [on the “Getting Involved” page](https://elementary.io/get-involved#translations) of the Elementary site. Thanks in advance for any contributions you offer